# Pass arguments to a callback function in jquery click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-callback

Straight to the business:

I have a jquery event listener that looks like this:

```
$(".number").click(printNumber);
```

and a callback function:

```
function printNumber(number){
   console.log(number);
}
```

I was wondering if I could pass an argument to a callback so it will look something like this

```
$(".number").click(printNumber(number));
```

(I know that it immediately invokes that function, but still, is there a way to pass arguments to it)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The clean way to handle this is to return a function:

```
function printNumber(number) {
   return function(e) {
       console.log(number);
   };
}
```

And then use:

```
$(".number").click(printNumber(number));
```

Answer (score 12):

You can pass data to the callback directly as [`event.data`](https://api.jquery.com/event.data/) in jQuery

```
$(".number").on('click', {number : 4}, printNumber);

function printNumber(event){
   console.log(event.data.number); // 4
}
```

Another way would be to use `bind`

```
$(".number").click(printNumber.bind($, 4));

function printNumber(number, event){
   console.log(number); // 4
}
```

But that would also change the callbacks `this` value

Comment: Returning the function is the cleaner way.

Comment: @RobertMoskal - passing `event.data` is the jQuery'ish way, it's why it's there

Comment: In printNumber code is not obvious that you have event.data.number, but it may be useful when $number.off('click', printNumber)

Comment: really thanx, bind worked for me